# How to Declare Folder Path?

Tags: java

I have a desktop application using Swing library. Application is running a batch file. So I created a `lib` folder in main project directory and put batch file in it. To run this, I am showing `lib\a.exe` to run this. It is working on my laptop. I exported .jar and put lib folder next to it. It is working on my laptop, but not working on some other laptops. How to fix this?

Error message is: Windows cannot found `lib\a.exe`.

```
String command = "cmd /c start lib\\a.exe";
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                increaseProgressBarValue();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Could you put some code?

Comment: Ok, I edited my question. It cannot found lib folder which is in the same folder with jar (but working on some computers). And I have to solve this in 5 minutes :)

Comment: You can get working directory 
`String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two things:

1. find the directory of the jar file of your application
2. call a.exe with the correct working directory

You can get the location of the jar with the getJar method below:

```
private static File getJar(Class clazz) throws MalformedURLException {
    String name = clazz.getName().replace('.','/') + ".class";
    ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL url = cl.getResource(name);
    System.out.println(url);
    if (!"jar".equals(url.getProtocol())) {
        throw new MalformedURLException("Expected a jar: URL " + url);
    }
    String file = url.getPath();
    int pos = file.lastIndexOf('!');
    if (pos < 0) {
        throw new MalformedURLException("Expected ! " + file);
    }
    url = new URL(file.substring(0, pos));
    if (!"file".equals(url.getProtocol())) {
        throw new MalformedURLException("Expected a file: URL " + url);
    }
    String path = url.getPath();
    if (path.matches("/[A-Za-z]:/")) { // Windoze drive letter
        path = path.substring(1);
    }
    return new File(path);
}
```

To call lib\a.exe, you can do something like this:

```
File jar = getJar(MyClass.class); // MyClass can be any class in you jar file
File dir = jar.getParentFile();
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command("lib\\a.exe");
builder.directory(dir);
...
Process p = builder.start();
...
```

Comment: Thank you, your approach is elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to try if this folder lib exists and if it doesn't than create it with

```
file.mkdir();
```

This is a just a checking. But your filepath must be like this ../lib/a.exe.

Comment: Your answer is totally irrelevent. I don't want to create a folder. There is already my lib folder next to jar!

Comment: Opps I forgot when you use some directories out of the jar you have to set the filepath like this ../lib/a.exe and will work fine. The problem is when the you are running the jar the JVM searching the lib flder somewhere in the jar. Try ../lib/a.exe